# Error al usar PDO con mdb: PDOException: nombre de fuente de datos no válido

Tags: php, base-de-datos, pdo, ms-access, odbc

Estoy tratando de conectarme a una base de datos de Access ubicada en la carpeta "bd" usando PDO para la cadena de conexión.

El problema es que constantemente me da el error "PDOException: nombre de fuente de datos no válido".

Intenté usar las soluciones que vienen en otras preguntas en este sitio web, pero nada ha funcionado. Estoy usando PHP x64 y el sistema también es x64.

Dejo el código aquí:

```
<?php
class db {
    
    private $conexion;
    private $name = 'coches.mdb';
    
    public function conectar(){
        $db = "bd\\" .$this->name;
       
     if(is_file($db)){
    
      
    $this->conexion = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$db");
             
     if($this->conexion){
          echo 'Conexión a ['.$this->name.'] : Establecida';
         
     }else
          exit("Error : No se pudo completar la conexion.");
     }
     else exit("Error : No existe archivo ".$this->name);
    }
    
    public function desconectar(){
        odbc_close($this->conexion);
        echo 'Conexion a ['.$this->name.'] : Terminado';
    }
}


#__________________________________________

$db = new db();
$db->conectar();
$db->desconectar();
?>
```

Gracias de antemano,
Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Has probado con el siguiente enlace? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066516/microsoft-access-with-php-and-pdo

Comment: Si, he probado con todos. Si escribo la cadena de conexión sin el odbc, es decir, ```Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$db"``` me da el error: "Invalid data source name".
Y por ultimo, si lo pongo como en ese ejemplo, el error que me da es: ```"SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No se encuentra el nombre del origen"```.

Comment: Por el ejemplo que he pasado, parece que tienes que poner la ruta al fichero indicado.

Comment: Tambien lo he probado, pero no ha surgido efecto. He cambiado un poco la cadena de conexión, y el error nuevo que me da es el siguiente:

`Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: 63 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x40b8 Thread 0x4848 DBC 0xca6cf138 Jet'`

Comment: Has probado poner la ruta completa en ```$db```, algo así, ```$db = "C:\\ruta\\a_tu\\basedatos.mdb";```,quedaria asi: ```$this->conexion = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$db; Uid=; Pwd=;");```

Comment: Has probado también de esta manera que tienes habilitado los driver: ```echo '<pre>'; print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); echo '</pre>';```, en caso que no tienes el **driver odbc**, debes activarlo en tu *PHP.ini*, buscando la línea **extensión=php_pdo_odbc.dll**

Comment: [Revisa esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26317631/5587982)  donde se enumeran las posibles causas del error que acabas de mencionar. Revisa que la ubicación del archivo es correcta, que el usuario tiene permisos, que la BD no está abierta de modo exclusivo por otro usuario/proceso, que tu versión de Access no es obsoleta, etc.